# CSS Sub Navigation Auto Width

Tags: css

This has been bugging me quite a while. Please look at my fiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/y9uEf/

You can see that the Subnav can't seem to "grow" bigger if there's a very long text in it. I know that it's because its width will always be 100% of the parent (in this case the top menu Home, Who, Contact). I can add width in the subnav ul so that the subnav ul will be bigger, but that will work on all subnavs regardign the width of the subnav content.

Now what if I want it to be dynamic? For instance, if the subnav content only has "Short Text" (let's say it's about 50 pixels), then the subnav width will be 50 pixels. Then if the subnav content has a list with "A Very Very Very Long Text" (let's say it's about 200 pixels) then the subnav width will automatically be 200px.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to add a `white-space: nowrap` to your `li`.

Comment: that works! thanks a lot. never thought of the relevance of white-space to width problem. lol